# I am stuck on a question Algebra:Sequence and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, partial-fractions, telescopic-series

This is a question I stumbled upon while learning sequence and series

> Is
>   $$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)...(r+m)}$$ the same as $$\frac1{m}\left(\frac1{1\times 2\times \cdots \times (m-1)}-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+m)}\right)?$$

A summary of what I tried so far is that I tried writing the denominators of the LHS into series and multiply to form a bigger series but the LHS after simplification did not convert to the RHS.I also tried to write the LHS as an AGP but it didn't work out.
So I would request you to please guide me with a hint, not a solution.

The answer is that both expressions are identical in terms of magnitude

Please note this is not my homework exercise, I am just learning algebra for my competitive examination preparation.

EDIT- Telescopicing sum will solve the question easily.

Comment: If the question has an issue please bring it to my notice, instead of down-voting, I will fix it as fast as I can

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos This time I wrote the question in MathJax myself, all the fear that I had regarding MathJax seems to have vanished into thin air

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: [Telescoping sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html) and
$$\frac{m}{r(r+1)(r+2)\cdots(r+m)}=\frac{1}{r(r+1)\cdots(r+m-1)}-\frac{1}{(r+1)(r+2)\cdots(r+m)}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I must have thought that way right at the start